How do I find the password to my privaterelay.appleid.com
I signed up with chatgpt using my apple id privaterelay.appleid.com which I regret doing because chatgpt claims they are sending my usage statistics to an account whose log in id is that privaterelay.  I can't log into that account because I don't what the password is for my privaterelay.appleid.com.  So suppose my email address were
123@privaterelay.appleid.com
How would I find out the password?
I would assume I go here
https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid
And I then enter in that email address but that doesn't work.

Apple forwards any mails sent to a privaterelay address to your iCloud mail address.

If you selected "Sign in with Apple" or "Continue with Apple" when you created the account, there is no password. Instead, there is a cryptographic key stored in iCloud. The only way you can sign in to the account is to select "Sign in with Apple" again.

@LincD. Hey, that's perfectly right, you should add that as an answer.

Apple does not issue a password for your private emails. You only have a password for your AppleID and that never is shared with other companies.

Private relay isn’t technically the same as Sign in with Apple or Hide My Email other than they all are bundled with iCloud+
If you create an account with another service, it’s up to that service to integrate with passcode via Sign in with Apple where your device will use your main iCloud credentials to unlock a Pass Key token stored on your device and send that token (which is not your AppleID or iCloud password) to log you in.
If that service (chatGPT in your case) forces you to choose a password, it’s likely you used Hide My Email only and whatever you chose to send to them for them to store and authenticate. Again, this isn’t your AppleID password unless you reused it.
If you aren’t sure which path the service let you choose, check with chatGPT customer support. Or you could try their password reset procedure which typically emails a reset link or uses SMS / two factor auth.

https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936828-how-do-i-change-my-account-password

You absolutely won’t use iforgot.apple.com in any case where you have a private alias or passcode sent to a third party. Only use “iforgot” if you can’t log in to https://appleid.apple.com with your Apple credentials.

If you selected "Sign in with Apple" or "Continue with Apple" when you created the account, there is no password. Instead, there is a cryptographic key stored in iCloud. The only way you can sign in to the account is to select "Sign in with Apple" again.
https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/
